# Scale down Image to fit Flex "sibling"

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm pretty new to CSS and I'm trying to build a Card-Component.

My problem is that the div with the text always adjusts to the height of the image and not the other way around. My goal is to have the image scale down in height so that it is exactly as high as the text-divs minimal height.

The Text-Content will be dynamic, so the height of the text-box will vary

current state:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA0H3.png)

Planned result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAnEJ.png)

Here's my current code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  /* width: 768px; */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  padding: 50px;
  background: green;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item card">
      <p>Some example Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item image">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ov9j5bnL/73/)

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Specify a `height` on your `flex-item` then use `height: inherit` on your image. I used the height that the `card` was rendering at to demonstrate.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  /* width: 768px; */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 155px;
}

.card {
  padding: 50px;
  background: green;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-item card">
        <p>Some example Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item image">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The content in the box will be dynamic, so this won't work in that case. Added this to my post now.